# Magento 2.4.1 controller cache control

Tags: cache, controllers, full-page-cache, magento2.4.1

It seems that on my Magento 2 instance the controller methods are somehow cached because I am doing changes, compiling the code, but they are not visible when they are called. I even added a `die()` within the main controller method, but I am getting the same result: the controller is not interrupted, running as expected.

This is the cache-control value: cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0.
The server is LiteSpeed, but I changed the caching source from LiteSpeed Web Server to Built-in.

What would be the cause and how can I prevent this?
The development process gets very slow and I can't just rename the controller each time to not serve it from cache again.

Looking forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: I investigated this further and found out it was from OP Cache. So, I deactivated OP Cache on the DEV environment.

Comment: Yes, Right OP Cache deactivated.